# Auto delete kafka consumer group after disconnect

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In my Java app, Once every couple of seconds, I'm  assigning a specific *TopicPartition* to the consumer, and trying to read specific message from specific topic + partition. After reading the message (using *poll()* ) I immediately disconnect the consumer.

Because the scenario above can run in multi-threaded environment The consumer group name has prefix + random hash e.g. *my_consumer_group_EWQSV* (since kafka will not assign **same** specific partition to two consumers on the same group).

The problem is, I couldn't tell kafka to delete those consumers after they disconnect (since those consumers are just temporary), is there any way of doing this? (not manually, I mean by using configuration or something, I wasn't able to find any conf like "auto-delete-after-consumer-disconnect")

Thanks :)

Comment: Why is it creating a problem for you?

Comment: well, after 1 day i will have hundreds of temporary consumer groups  which will never be used again

Comment: Is there a problem to create cron Job cleaning everything older than 1 day? On operating system level.

Answer (score 2):

In java, in order to manually consume specific message from kafka without creating consumer group:

The following is sufficient:

```
kafkaProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        kafkaProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition(topic, partition);
        try (Consumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(kafkaProps)) {
            consumer.assign(Collections.singletonList(tp));
            consumer.seek(tp, offset);
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000L));
        }
```

The important parts are:

- set enable.auto.commit property to false (as shown above).
- do **NOT** set group.id (*ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG*) property because id isn't needed.
- do **NOT** use *subscribe* method which automatically assign partitions, instead use assign and seek methods to manually read message as shown above.